# how to create blades ui using react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

As explained here [blades for sequential data entry](https://liftcodeplay.com/2015/11/12/design-pattern-blades-for-sequential-data-entry-wizards-in-uwp/), blade ui patter seems pretty interesting. How we can implement such UI layout in reactJS. Is there a module like bladerunnerjs in react world which can help us implement blade design in react.

Comment: This is *way* too broad for Stack Overflow, we deal more with specific debugging issues, not "how would I implement this entire detailed system".

Comment: @Jayce444 i have edited the question. i mean to ask if we do have a module which can help us build such system. like we have react-final-from, react-tables and others.